# How to Book Appointment If user is not logged , Most preferred flow or solution

Tags: java

For book appointment, if the user is not logged in we have to launch logged in screen and then the book appointment form, book appointment form has booking details (Ley us suppose it has Bundle of data already but the user cannot book an appointment without logging).

BookAppointmetActivity Flow

1. If user not logged in -> BookAppointmentActiivty(Booking details data already saved) => launch Login in Screen => Book Appointment Activity
2. If user is logged in => Book Appointment Activity - Booking success

My question is which would be the most preferred solution to solve this situation and why need the explanation?

- solution 1: We can solve this thing via the startActivityForResult concept
- solution 2: start login activity from booking activity send details of booking activity to the login screen, then again launch booking activity with booking details sending

Comment: what does this have to do with java?  This question is very unclear.  Nobody here knows what a "BookAppointmetActivity Flow" is. If you have any  relevant code, please post a [mcve]. thanks